# Maven Goal not getting executed

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have some maven goals defined as follows:

```
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-from-tenant-lcm</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/resources/db/changelog</outputDirectory>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>${basedir}/../srv-tenant-lcm/src/main/resources/db/changelog
              </directory>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
```

If I run this goal independently using `mvn resources:copy-resources@copy-from-tenant-lcm`  it works as expected, but not as part of `mvn clean install`. Would expect this to run as part of install phase as well.

Any idea what I am missing out?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the phase to process-resources instead of install.